# Bootstrap-Vue: Table: Get index which doesn't change after sorting a column

Tags: bootstrap-vue

How to get an index like 0, 1, 2, 3... which doesn't change after sorting a column ?

I have add the `primary-key` prop to `<b-table>`, but the initial index is reinitialized after a column is sorted (by clicking the arrays in a column title).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :fields="fields" :items="items" primary-key>
      <!-- A virtual column -->
      <template slot="index" slot-scope="data">
        {{ data.index }}
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fields: [
          "index",
          {
            key: 'last_name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'first_name',
            sortable: false
          },
          {
            key: 'age',
            label: 'Person age',
            sortable: true
          }
        ],
        items: [
          { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prop `primary-key` needs reference a field name in your item data.  Just like a primary-key in a database, this item data field needs to be unique across all item rows. It also does not need to be listed in your fields definition if you don't want it to be visible to the user.

i.e.

```js
    items: [
      { index: 1, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
      { index: 2, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
      { index: 3, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
      { index: 4, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
    ]
```

The index that is passed to any row-clicked handlers still refers to the visual index (i.e. which row it is showing as).  but you can access the item data in the events and reference your unique index column name (i.e. `index` in the above items example).

Comment: How do you actually set the primary key, is it something like this?
`<b-table :primary-key="index"></b-table>`

Comment: nvm, found it, you must send item prop as string like this `<b-table ::primary-key="'index'"></b-table>